# Custom node.js cartridge to support custom npm and node engine on Openshift

Tags: openshift

Is there a cartridge for Node.js to run custom version of node and npm
I would prefer npm engine 1.4.3

I tried the following catridge repos:

1) https://github.com/Filirom1/openshift-cartridge-nodejs

2) https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/tree/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-nodejs

I get the following error

```
 The cartridge manifest at 'xxxx' must be smaller than 20480 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually point people to this blog article when they want a custom node.js version (https://www.openshift.com/blogs/any-version-of-nodejs-you-want-in-the-cloud-openshift-does-it-paas-style), but I'm not sure about the custom npm version.

Comment: git://github.com/openshift/nodejs-custom-version-openshift.git worked, but I had a weird situation, npm install that runs automatically with each push, ran using default npm engine, after I SSH and did npm install that worked fine using specified version. Any idea why would that happen?

Comment: Maybe try a stop & start on your gear after you do the install, to make sure it picks up any new environment variables

Comment: my bad, my comment was for https://github.com/ryanj/nodejs-custom-version-openshift. I will try this one, is there a way to specify the npm engine version as well?

Answer (score 0):

This comes a bit late, but if you're looking to get the latest Node.js & NPM versions, you can also try this one: https://github.com/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-nodejs

There are brief how-to & FAQ sections in the project README that will explain you exactly what to do, but basically this is how it works:

Go to [Choose a type of application](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/application_types) in your OpenShift Online account, paste the URL below into "Code Anything" textbox at the bottom of the page and click "Next".

http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/github/icflorescu/openshift-cartridge-nodejs